How to divide by two dynamic values for ArcGIS Pro Report script generation
For our property assessment staff, we have a script tool where they take their parcel selection, specify certain parameters, and then run the tool. The tool creates a Report with parcel records and information. For one section of the report, I want to divide the value field dynamic value by the square_feet field dynamic value to generate a value per square footage value for each record in the report. For some reason, I can't find any documentation on this. I've tried the following different ways (parentheses placed in different areas, quotation marks, brackets, no extra marks other than / for division):

$<dyn type="report" property="field-value" field="value"/>/<dyn type="report" property="field-value" field="square_feet"/> /Sq. Ft.

$)<dyn type="report" property="field-value" field="value"/>)/(<dyn type="report" property="field-value" field="square_feet"/>) /Sq. Ft.

$)<dyn type="report" property="field-value" field="value"/>/<dyn type="report" property="field-value" field="square_feet"/>) /Sq. Ft.

$[<dyn type="report" property="field-value" field="value"/>]/[<dyn type="report" property="field-value" field="square_feet"/>] /Sq. Ft.


None of these have given me the desired result.
Has anyone had any success with this? For reference, I'm using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.

I have to admit I've not used reports in ArcPro but a quick whizz around the help file on that topic I came to the conclusion that computing a value within a dynamic text is not possible. I suspect you need to create a field and pre-compute that value? Happy for someone to shoot me down in flames on this!

@Hornbydd It might be possible to set up an extra field and have attribute rules automatically calculate the value into it for displaying in the dynamic textbox.  I unfortunately don't currently have ArcGIS Pro to test it

I thought it would be simple for some reason (like it was in ArcMap!) but rather than continue to mess around with it, I did what you said and set up the extra field, calculated the value, and then chose that attribute for the dynamic text. It gets the job done! @Midavalo
